# How long do I have until my crops wither?

Tags: smurfs-village

I know if I leave my crops for too long, they wither. It seems to vary crop to crop, but is  there a standard (a percentage of total time of growth, or something) measurement of how long I have before they wither?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [My Smurfs Village](http://www.mysmurfsvillage.com/smurfs-village-guide/growing-crops/):

> Crops can take up to 24 hours before they are ready to harvest and they can also wilt. **After a crop is done it must be harvested within the same time frame that was needed to grow it, otherwise it will wilt** (i.e. if a crop takes six hours to grow, it will wilt after another six hours). The only exception to that rule are the blueberries, they wilt after five minutes, even so they only need 30 seconds to grow.

I think this is pretty clear. The percentage of total time you were looking for is 100% (except for blueberries), so it indeed changes with crop.